# cannot assign django.contrib.auth.models.User to filed using south migration

Tags: python, django, django-south

For my django1.4 app,I am trying to use south to do migration of data.I am using postgres8.3

I have a `MyCategory` model for which I need to add a field called `creator` which is a django.contrib.auth.models.User

I modified the class and added the field

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class MyCategory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=50)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)#added
    slug=models.SlugField(editable=False)
```

I ran `python manage.py schemamigration myapp --auto`

which output `+ Added field creator on myapp.MyCategory`
and created a file `0003_auto__add_field_mycategory_creator.py`

Then I wanted all old records to have the superuser of the webapp as creator .So I tried datamigration

I ran `python manage.py datamigration myapp add_creator`

This output a file add_creator.py in which I implemented the forwards method as below.(later I added a print stmt for debug purpose)

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    suser = User.objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
    # I also tried User.objects.get(is_superuser=True)
    print 'suser=',suser,'of type=',type(suser)
    for category in orm.MyCategory.objects.all():
        category.creator = suser
        category.save()
```

Then I ran the migrate command

`python manage.py migrate myapp`

This output a `ValueError`

```
Running migrations for myapp:
 - Migrating forwards to 0004_add_creator.
 > myapp:0004_add_creator
suser= damon of type= <class 'django.contrib.auth.models.User'>
Error in migration: myapp:0004_add_creator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
....
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/south/migration/migrators.py", line 57, in <lambda>
    return (lambda: direction(orm))
  File "/home/me/dev/python/django/myapp/migrations/0004_add_creator.py", line 14, in forwards
    category.creator = suser
  File "/home/me/Django-1.4/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 366, in __set__
    self.field.name, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name))
ValueError: Cannot assign "<User: damon>": "MyCategory.creator" must be a "User" instance.
```

I don't understand what is happening here..The print statement shows that the user `damon` is of type `django.contrib.auth.models.User` ..Is `south` expecting some other type? Can someone please help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you are going to need to freeze `django.contrib.auth` in your data migration. That can be achieved by:

```
python manage.py datamigration myapp add_creator --freeze auth
```

Second you are going to need to reference your objects properly through the `orm` dictionary:

```
def forwards(self, orm):
    suser = orm['auth.User'].objects.filter(is_superuser=True)[0]
    print 'suser=',suser,'of type=',type(suser)
    for category in orm['myapp.MyCategory'].objects.all():
        category.creator = suser
        category.save()
```